# create folder in android and save media and file in folder with flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I have chatroom app, and I want to save media and file in folder to show media in gallery.
I save media and file in ExternalStorageDirectory now ,but media not showen in gallery.
how to can save media in my custom folder to showen in gallery of phone?

Comment: Reboot your device.